# Exclude documents from $geoNear selection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two Collections `Cards` and `Swipes`. User can request a list of cards and swipe on them. Once the user has swiped the card I don't want that card to appear in the list again i.e. I only want cards that are not swiped by the user.

One way of doing it is using `$nin`. But I'm concerned about the performance of querying using `$nin` because the array will increase with time. Using `$nin` with an array of 1000 items is not a good idea.

Is there any alternative way of performing this query?

```
db.Cards.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [ 77.209, 28.6139 ]
            },
            maxDistance: 100,
            distanceField: "distance",
            spherical: true
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            _id: { $nin: [ <array of ~1000 items> ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { createdAt: -1 }
    },
    {
        $limit: 10
    }
]);
```

The `$geoNear` pipeline will limit the documents to not more than 500 then I want to apply the $nin to get only the documents which are not already swiped. Also I'm not sure if the sequence of the pipeline matters in the aggregate method.

I'm open to suggestion on how I can optimise this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) aggregation pipeline stage has a "query" option:

```js
db.Cards.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [ 77.209, 28.6139 ]
            },
            maxDistance: 100,
            distanceField: "distance",
            spherical: true,
            query: { "_id": { "$nin": [ <array of ~1000 items> ] } }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { distance:1, createdAt: -1 }
    },
    {
        $limit: 10
    }
]);
```

This will be combined in the "near" operation to also exclude those documents directly from selection. That saves quite a bit of time in processing since it does not need an additional stage of execution to process it.

Also it does not make much sense when doing any kind of "near" operation to not sort by the nearest distance first.

As to the basic concept you don't really have a choice. Operations like `$geoNear` or `$nearSphere` require an index to perform the query. You can emulate joins with `$lookup`, but since you would have to do that "before" the `$geoNear` then it could not be in the first pipeline stage, where it must be.

Even using `$geoWitin` and a "Polygon" emulating the radius does not actually return a "distance" projection, so it is not going to find the "nearest" for terms of limiting results.

The only real way you can optimize this out of the `$nin` condition is to include the necessary data out of the other collection directly in the collection with the geolocation data. Then all query conditions can be specified at once, using the same "query" option.

---

### Example of differing behavior

Since you seem to be missing the point here, it stands to reason that others may as well, so a practical example is likely appropriate. For this I will use a [dataset readily available from the MongoDB site](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/import-data/).

Following those import instructions you would then create the appropriate index on the restaurants collection:

```js
db.restaurants.createIndex({ "address.coord": "2dsphere" })
```

Then let's get the top 5 results nearest to a location:

```js
var exclude = db.restaurants.find({
  "address.coord": {
    "$nearSphere": {
      "$geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -73.9829239,
          40.6580753
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},{ "_id": 1 }).limit(5).toArray().map((el) => { return el._id })
```

The `exclude` variable should then contain this content, which is the _id value from those 5 nearest documents:

```js
[
        ObjectId("56e21e330c502e7d3727b133"),
        ObjectId("56e21e330c502e7d3727b977"),
        ObjectId("56e21e330c502e7d3727d02b"),
        ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d37281121"),
        ObjectId("56e21e330c502e7d3727d45d")
]
```

Then we first demonstrate using the same approach you have where the `$match` with `$nin` is run after the initail pipeline stage:

```js
db.restaurants.aggregate([
  { "$geoNear": {
    "near": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -73.9829239,
        40.6580753
      ]
    },
    "spherical": true,
    "distanceField": "distance",
    "limit": 10
  }},
  { "$match": { "_id": { "$nin": exclude } } },
  { "$project": { "distance": 1 }}
])
```

What I want to demonstrate here is that even though the "near" is looking for the 10 nearest, the results will exlcude the first 5 and then only return the next 5:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727e0cd"), "distance" : 87.43379780572778 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727de6b"), "distance" : 88.18009275622559 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727fd53"), "distance" : 110.40877485624807 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e21e330c502e7d3727d317"), "distance" : 125.18596173260741 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727da21"), "distance" : 142.62225533420892 }
```

By contrast, when we "include" the "query" option, those nearest 5 are already excluded from the results. Hence then you actually get the 10 results you asked for:

```js
db.restaurants.aggregate([
  { "$geoNear": {
    "near": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -73.9829239,
        40.6580753
      ]
    },
    "spherical": true,
    "distanceField": "distance",
    "query": { "_id": { "$nin": exclude }},
    "limit": 10
  }},
  { "$project": { "distance": 1 }}
])
```

With the proper results:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727e0cd"), "distance" : 87.43379780572778 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727de6b"), "distance" : 88.18009275622559 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727fd53"), "distance" : 110.40877485624807 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e21e330c502e7d3727d317"), "distance" : 125.18596173260741 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727da21"), "distance" : 142.62225533420892 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727d8e1"), "distance" : 155.15302440129824 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d37280491"), "distance" : 161.1217883163846 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d37280c71"), "distance" : 198.54060208357487 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727ebd1"), "distance" : 231.1351850943389 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727f55d"), "distance" : 273.94030274423943 }
```

So this is the same as the following query issued with `$geoNear`, with the exception of not projecting the `"distance"` field and value:

```js
db.restaurants.find({
  "_id": { "$nin": exclude },
  "address.coord": {
    "$nearSphere": {
      "$geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -73.9829239,
          40.6580753
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},{ "_id": 1 }).limit(10).toArray().map((el) => { return el._id })

Which returns:

[
        ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727e0cd"),
        ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727de6b"),
        ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727fd53"),
        ObjectId("56e21e330c502e7d3727d317"),
        ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727da21"),
        ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727d8e1"),
        ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d37280491"),
        ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d37280c71"),
        ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727ebd1"),
        ObjectId("56e21e340c502e7d3727f55d")
]
```

So the "query" option allows the "combination" of conditions, which is completely different to fetching the results and then removing the ones you want to exclude after the fact.

The simulation of the `"limit": 10` option is there since there is a **real** limit on what `$geoNear` returns, and when filtering out a large list, you run the real risk of removing **all* results from the query, which is clearly not desired.

So to get the *"nearest things exluding these items"* then you want this to be part of the "same query" in selection, as opposed to stripping them from the results "after" you made the query selection.

Comment: Okay so having 1000 items in the array won't increase the execution time? I mean the documents returned after the $geoNear pipeline will be less than 500 so how long will it take to execute the $nin operation with an array of 1000 ids? Should I consider it or not?

Comment: @Chaitanya Will it increase execution? Not terribly no. The only real restriction is that the pipeline query content itself, as is a common MongoDB restriction cannot exceed the 16MB BSON limit on transmission to the server. But that would take a really big document and a lot more than 1000 ids. Also noted is the difference here that by including in the "near" query option as opposed to a later `$match` stage, the documents are exluded from the returned results, rather than exlcuding "after" the return. Understand the difference in approaches now?

Comment: @Chaitanya Also the default documents to return from `$geoNear` is 100. But like I said, used in the context I have you would always get the nearest 100 "after" the list had been excluded. Your context could possibly exclude everything if all 100 nearest where in your array. And of course there is the `"limit"` option to `$geoNear`, so you can tune how many documents you want to return.

Comment: Okay thank you. So basically I'll have to specify if I want more than 100 documents to be returned using $geoNear.

Comment: @Chaitanya Arrgh! No you don't **have** to at all. `{ "$geoNear": { ... "query": { "$nin":.... } }}` **always** returns 100 documents ( provided there are more than 100 in the collection). By contrast `{ "$geoNear": { ... } },{ "$match": { "$nin"....: }}` likely **will not** return 100 documents if any of the `$nin` list was in the top 100 results. What I have been explaining over and over is the difference between "before" filtering and "after" filtering. Hopefully third time is the charm and this time it sticks that you actually understand.

Comment: @Chaitanya Since you still don't seem to be understanding the concept, I have included a practical example you can reproduce using data obtained from the MongoDB site. This demonstrates why you should be querying as given in the answer.

Comment: Okay, Now I got it. That example you mentioned in the answer was really helpful. Sorry I'm a slow learner. Thank You so much :)